# color selected row in jtable by another color

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rendering, selection

I use this code to color the rows of ly jtable by differents colors :

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer()
    {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
        {
            final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

            return c;
        }
    });
```

it works, now I want to color the row selected by the user to another color diferent than those above  with :

```
table.setSelectionBackground(Color.RED);
```

but it does anything
How can I achieve this ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Your renderer is overriding the color change applied by the `DefaultTableCellRenderer`

Try something like...

```
Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
if (!isSelected) {
    c.setBackground(row % 2 == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
}
```

Instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getSelectedRow()` or `getSelectedColumn()`, depending on your needs. For example:

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        comp.setForeground(Color.BLACK); // Default colour of cell
        if (this.getSelectedRow() == row || this.getSelectedColumn() == column) return comp;
        else { 
          .... // Other formatting rules here
        }

        return comp;
}
```